# Galvanometer Question

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits

[image: Galvanometer]

As seen in the figure, the rectangular coil is wound over a soft iron cylinder. As stated by my textbook and online, the cylinder is used so that the field of the coil is made radial. Also the poles of the magnet are made concave so that the magnet's field can be made radial as well. If both the field are radial and in the same direction, would the conductor still experience force? If so, how? Should the fields be in different directions to produce a net result?

Comment: The coil isn't wound aroudn the circumference of the cylinder it's around the length - so has a force around the axis ie at 90deg to the coil

Comment: Have you read in your textbook how the galvanometer works? Force on current-carrying wire in magnetic field : F=BIL. Not the interaction of 2 magnetic fields.

Answer (score 0):

The cylinder IS a pole piece of the magnet, just as the concave shapes are.  The induction of the winding is hoop-like, not radial at all.

So, the cylinder makes the permanent magnet field nearly radial, not the 'field of the coil', but the permanent magnet field that permeates the space in which
the coil moves.

Without field shaping, a dipole field and coil would give sine(theta) dependence on current, instead of (roughly) theta dependence.

Comment: so the cylinder is used to change the orientation of the field of the permanent magnet?

Comment: and why are the poles made concave then? Don't they serve the purpose of making the field radial?

Comment: Maximum force on  current-carrying wire occurs when the B field is perpendicular to the wire.  This condition holds if B is radial, and the wire is parallel to the rotation axis.   So, the outer wire runs of the square loop get maximum torque when the field in their vicinity is radial.

Comment: And, the cylinder core inside the C-shaped poles makes a uniform gap distance, which keeps B nearly constant in magnitude as well as radial in orientation.